# Easy conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm beginning to grasp on to conditional probability, but I have a quick and dirty question that I cannot find the answer to on the internet (but I think is really easy). Is P(B|A) equal to P(B)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$$

$P(B|A)=P(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.  If they are then,
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)P(A)}{P(A)}=P(B).$$

Comment: Have heard the definition, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @louiemcconnell please see above.

Comment: ah, you changed it. Thanks, this helps.

Comment: I think you meant it equal $P(B)$

Comment: @Kamster Right, thanks.  I've corrected it.